# Create multiple Google accounts as a developer

Tags: google-analytics, accounts

I am a web developer, and offer the creation of Google Analytics accounts for clients. To save them messing around with veifying email accounts, I like to create them a gmail account, get it all set up then just send them the password.

However, Google is asking for verification by Mobile and I have now reached the "verification limit".

I kind of understand why Google don't want spam accounts, but is there no way to regsiter as a developer and then create accounts for clients? Something like apps for business, but just for standard Google accounts.

Comment: Have you considered just using a single account and creating profiles limited to the client?  You don't even need to setup a gmail account, just send the access invite to whatever existing email address they have.

Comment: I hadn't. Will have to do more experimenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @CrayonViolent it looks like profiles is the way forward

Answer (score 0):

I would be a mistake to use profiles for multiple clients.  For one, each client would be prevented from using more than one profile.  And there is a limit of 50 profiles per account.

Comment: I think the questioner is proposing to set up a new account for each client.